# Can't resolve 'products.json' in absolute path file location in vue/webpack

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, webpack

I'm attempting to import some json data from a json file, into a component. The goal is to import the json, then assign it to the props that gets exported from the parent component. Then import the props into the child component, which would, using a v-for, render the json data in the component's template format. 
I'm new to Vue though, and this is an example product I'm attempting to learn from basically. So it's already got quite a bit set up for me, and the goal is to import the json data.

The json file is located in `/src/assets/products.json'`. In `webpack.config.json`, I've configured the data to be assigned to an alias:

```
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, './src'), 'node_modules'],
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".json"],
    alias: {
      Src: CONTEXT_PATH,
      products: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/assets/products.json")
    },
```

Then, in `product.vue`, which is intended to render a single product, I have the following:

```
import products from './src/assets/products.json'

export default {
  props: ['productData'],

  data: () => ({
    hotDealsImg: 'https://www.roguefitness.com/skin/frontend/rg/2015/images/matte-black-friday/hot-deal-icon-2015.jpg',
  }),
```

And in `products.vue`,

```
import productData from '../components/product.vue'
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
ERROR in ../node_modules/babel-loader/lib!../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./js/components/product.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/assets/products.json' in '/Users/mikeearley/code/front-end-dev-test-2/src/js/components'
resolve './src/assets/products.json' in '/Users/mikeearley/code/front-end-dev-test-2/src/js/components'
  using description file: /Users/mikeearley/code/front-end-dev-test-2/package.json (relative path: ./src/js/components)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: /Users/mikeearley/code/front-end-dev-test-2/package.json (relative path: ./src/js/components)
    using description file: /Users/mikeearley/code/front-end-dev-test-2/package.json (relative path: ./src/js/components/src/assets/products.json)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /Users/mikeearley/code/front-end-dev-test-2/src/js/components/src/assets/products.json doesn't exist
      .js
```

Sample of products.json data I'm trying to import:

```
  {
    "sku": "XX45",
    "name": "Rogue Gymnastic Wood Rings",
    "brand": "Rogue",
    "placeholder": "https://via.placeholder.com/200x200",
    "image": "https://www.roguefitness.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/200x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/r/o/rogue-wood-rings-th-resize_1_.jpg",
    "url": "https://www.roguefitness.com/rogue-dumbbells",
    "price": 7,
    "rating": 4.9,
    "startingAt": true,
    "specialPrice": false,
    "promotions": [
      "Made In USA",
      "3 Ships Free"
    ]
  },
  {
    "sku": "XX7337",
    "name": "The Ohio Bar",
    "brand": "Rogue",
    "placeholder": "https://via.placeholder.com/200x200",
    "image": "https://www.roguefitness.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/200x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/o/h/ohio-bar-th_1__2.png",
    "url": "https://www.roguefitness.com/the-ohio-bar",
    "price": 282,
    "rating": 4.9,
    "startingAt": false,
    "specialPrice": false,
    "promotions": [
      "Made In USA",
      "3 Ships Free"
    ]
  },
```

Comment: try `../assets/products.json`

Comment: Same error. 
`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../assets/products.json' in '/Users/mikeearley/code/front-end-dev-test-2/src/js/components'
resolve '../assets/products.json' in '/Users/mikeearley/code/front-end-dev-test-2/src/js/components'
  using description file: /Users/mikeearley/code/front-end-dev-test-2/package.json (relative path: ./src/js/components)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: /Users/mikeearley/code/front-end-dev-test-2/package.json (relative path: ./src/js/components)`

Comment: please provide your project structure

Comment: See above, I added a snap of the structure

Comment: try the relative path `../../assets/products.json`

Comment: So that's working--the next part of my question is how to map 'products' from json to 'productData'. Am I even importing the json in the right place?

Comment: you could update your question with some of json file content and your second question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181963/discussion-between-mike-earley-and-boussadjra-brahim).

Comment: Don't ask two questions at once. [ask]